# NiFi: ListFile Processor is not detecting file changes sometimes

Tags: apache-nifi

ListFile processor is not detecting any changes to a previously processed file and reprocess it. FYI, I have tried the following options already for reprocessing and only the finally mentioned hack is working. This is in a single-node NiFi I am running in my development environment.

- Update Scenario: ListFile processor is not detecting file content changes and trigger automatically post-update (i.e file updates using VIM editor)
- Timestamp modification Scenario: Changing the file timestamp with `touch -c` command changes the file timestamp but this does not cause auto-trigger of the ListFile processor either.
- Stop-start Scenario: Stop-start of the whole process group in NiFi after changing the file as mentioned above also does not cause triggering of ListFile processor.
- Waiting Clause: Waiting for long enough after file change also does not help - just in case we assume it will auto-trigger after some delay.
- **HACK**: The only way I am able to trigger the re-processing of the file by ListFile processor is by changing the wildcard expression for "File Filter" in ListFile processor in a harmless, idempotent manner, for example from `.*test.*\.csv` to `test.*\.csv` and vice versa later (i.e go back and forth like this for repeated reprocessing).

Reprocessing of files with same old names and with modified data is a requirement for us. Please help!

And sometimes forced reprocessing of even an unmodified file could be required in case of unanticipated data issues upstream/downstream. Please help!

#### UPDATE

Still facing this sporadic behavior! Only restart of NiFi helps when the ListFile processor fails to respond to file change.

Comment: Try ensuring that the `ListFile` processor has this configuration: `Minimum File Age=0 sec`, `Maximum File Age is empty`, `Minimum File Size=0B`, `Maximum File Size is empty`.

Comment: Can you please show your `ListFile` configuration? And which version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: What version of NiFi do you use? I have just checked this in 1.5.0 and it worked correctly.

Comment: @JagrutSharma - The min/max properties are left to default which is matching what you have mentioned (Minimum File Age=0 sec, Maximum File Age is empty, Minimum File Size=0B, Maximum File Size is empty).

Comment: @mateharu - I am using NiFi 1.6.0. ListFile is identifying file change sometimes but does not identify sometimes!

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman - NiFi version is 1.6.0 and ListFile config as JSON is as follows: `[{"key": "Input Directory", "value": "/tmp/input"}, {"key": "Recurse Subdirectories", "value": "true"}, {"key": "Input Directory Location", "value": "Local"}, {"key": "File Filter", "value": ".*test.*\\.csv"}, {"key": "Path Filter"}, {"key": "Minimum File Age", "value": "0 sec"}, {"key": "Maximum File Age"}, {"key": "Minimum File Size", "value": "0 B"}, {"key": "Maximum File Size"}, {"key": "Ignore Hidden Files", "value": "true"}, {"key": "target-system-timestamp-precision", "value": "auto-detect"}]`

Comment: Can you reset `File Filter` with the default value i.e. `[^\.].*` and run the processor and put more files in that directory and see if it picks up all the files correctly?

Comment: Maybe something is messed up with timestamps maintained by the processor... Have you tried clearing its state? This option is disabled when ListFile is running. Stop the processor -> right click -> View state -> Clear state. All matching files should be picked up once the processor is started again regardless if those files were already processed or not.

Comment: @mateharu - Thanks for the processor state clearing tip. This will help in development environment. For production environment, the file changes should be detected without manual intervention.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman - Thanks for the file filter default value tip. The production use case is to identify changes to an existing file only. Also, my configuration is working fine occasionally - which is the strange part!

Answer (score 5):

Probably this is delayed answer.
The old List processors like ListFiles/ListFtp/ListSftp etc. used only timestamp tracking strategy to identify the changed files. The processor used to cache last seen timestamp in its processor state and use it to list files with only greater timestamp.
However, this approach was very buggy. Hence they had to come up with much better strategy which is called [Entity Tracking](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5406). This approach gives broad 
 range of monitoring on file changes. It keeps track of below parameters of each file in the specified directory.

1. Name
2. Size
3. Last modified timestamp

Any change in file is reflected in these key parameters. Since they are cached, any difference is treated as change, thus changed files appear in the success connection.

Comment: I am also facing same issues with ListSFTP - Fetch SFTP - PutSFTP process flow.

could you please update me, how u fixed this issue.